# Sql - Stored Procedure with multiple if condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is the table I have Created with the records

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Graph](
[RequestID] [int] NOT NULL,[ModuleName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[Info] [float] NULL,[HR] [float] NULL,[SR] [float] NULL, [ISIM] [float] NULL,[RequestCreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,[RequestModifiedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
```

| RequestID | ModuleName | Info | HR | SR | ISIM | RequestCreatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | ECE | 7 | 7 | 4 | 8 | 2023-01-09 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 1001 | EEE | 9 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 1002 | ECE | 5 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 2023-01-29 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 1003 | EEE | 6 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 2023-03-08 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 1004 | CSE | 8 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 2023-04-04 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 1005 | CSE | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2023-04-17 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 1006 | CSE | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 2023-05-09 00:00:00.0000000 |

I have tried to create a Stored procedure with multiple 'if' conditions like

1.ModuleName = null, it has to calculate the average of columns 'Info',' HR',' SR', and 'ISIM' from start to end.

2.ModuleName = CSE, it has to calculate the average of columns 'Info',' HR',' SR', and 'ISIM' of module name with CSE only.

3.if start_date = null, end_date = null means it has to show all the requests from the start of the requestcreateddate to the till date.

4.if start_date = some date(eg02-02-2023), end_date = null means it has to show the requests from that particular start_date to the till date.

5.if start_date = some date (eg 02-02-2023), end_date = some date (eg 30-04-2023) means it has to show only the request created in between that particular start_date and end_date.

6.if start_date = null and end_date = some date (30-04-2023) means it has to show the request created from the start to the end_date.

I just tried writing this stored procedure, but I exactly don't know how to write a query for these conditions, can someone help me in writing a stored procedure query including these conditions? I'm a beginner in this. Thanks.

```
Alter proc avg_calc (
@module_name  nvarchar(max) = Null,@start_date datetime2 = null,
@end_date datetime2 = null)
As
Begin
Declare @sql nvarchar(max), @where nvarchar(max) = '' , @where1 datetime2 = ''
    set @sql = 'Select AVG(Info) as Info,
    AVG([HR]) as [HR],
    AVG([SR]) as [SR],
    AVG([ISIM]) as [ISIM]
FROM Graph'
If @module_name is not null
set @where = @where + 'AND ModuleName = @_module_name'
If @start_date is not null 
set @where1 = @where1 + 'AND RequestCreatedDate = @_start_date '
If @end_date is not null 
set @where1 = @where1 + 'AND RequestModifiedDate = @_end_date '

If LEN(@where) > 0
Set @sql = @sql + 'WHERE' + RIGHT(@where, LEN(@where)-5)
If LEN(@where1) > 0
Set @sql = @sql + 'WHERE' +RIGHT(@where1, LEN(@where1)-10)

Exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@_module_name nvarchar(100)', 
@_module_name = @module_name

Exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@_start_date datetime2, @_end_date datetime2', 
@_start_date = @start_date, @_end_date = @end_date

End 


EXEC avg_calc @module_name='CSE'

EXEC avg_calc @start_date = 02-02-2023, @end_date = 30-02-2023
```

Comment: I would default your WHERE to be WHERE 1=1  That way all your following statements will just need AND.  That way you dont have to check to see if you need to add WHERE key word or add it multiple times.  Then in your if checks you just add AND column checks.  Then you can eliminate all the multiple where variables and the where length checks.  If you still have questions post here and I will try to post more code when I get a chance.

Comment: @Brad Thanks, I'm still a beginner so I don't get it properly. If possible, Can you please explain me with the code?

Comment: `WHERE 1=1` + `AND optional_condition` + `AND some_other_condition`

Comment: @MatBailie Can you please explain me with some more code?

Comment: Did you just delete and repost this? Please don't do that, it's not appreciated by the community

Comment: @Charlieface No it's not like that, There is some error from my side. So I deleted and reposted it. Sorry about that, I won't do it again.

Comment: @aniH https://dbfiddle.uk/oq1UPxSa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `sp_executesql` twice, plus `@where1` is a `datetime2` which makes no sense.

Furthermore, it's unclear which date field you want to filter. You have two and are filtering against one for the start and the other for the end.

Pay attention to data types: is `@module_name` supposed to be `nvarchar(max)` or `nvarchar(100)`?

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROC avg_calc
  @module_name nvarchar(100) = NULL,
  @start_date datetime2 = NULL,
  @end_date datetime2 = NULL
AS

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = '
SELECT
    AVG(Info) AS Info,
    AVG(HR) AS HR,
    AVG(SR) AS SR,
    AVG(ISIM) AS ISIM
FROM Graph
WHERE 1=1';

IF @module_name IS NOT NULL
    SET @sql += '
  AND ModuleName = @module_name';

IF @start_date IS NOT NULL
    SET @sql += '
  AND RequestCreatedDate >= @start_date';

IF @end_date IS NOT NULL
    SET @sql += '
  AND RequestCreatedDate < @end_date';

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@module_name nvarchar(100),
    @start_date datetime2,
    @end_date datetime2', 
  @module_name = @module_name
  @start_date = @start_date,
  @end_date = @end_date;
```

Also note the use of `>=` and `<` for the dates. For example, if you want results for the whole of `2023-05-10` you should pass in `2023-05-10 00:00:00` and `2024-05-11 00:00:00`.

Comment: I just noticed that the start date is applied against the created date, but the end date is applied against the modified date. The OP needs to pay a little more attention to detail.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to use dynamic SQL for this task. You could simply use something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE avg_calc (
@module_name  nvarchar(max) = Null,
@start_date datetime2 = null,
@end_date datetime2 = null)
AS
SELECT AVG(Info) as Info,
    AVG([HR]) as [HR],
    AVG([SR]) as [SR],
    AVG([ISIM]) as [ISIM]
FROM Graph
WHERE (ModuleName = @module_name OR @module_name IS NULL)
AND (RequestCreatedDate >= @start_date OR @start_date IS NULL)
AND (RequestCreatedDate <= @end_date OR @end_date IS NULL)
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

I have used `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to try to use an optimal execution plan for each execution, assuming that this procedure is not executed very often, but the table size is quite big (so the compilation time would be negligible compared to the execution time) and there are some indexes on `ModuleName` and `RequestCreatedDate`. If this assumption is incorrect, you should remove `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`.

For more information, please read https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html.

Comment: Sorry, But I have tried this link and already tried something like this code, it's not working in my conditions that's why I choose Dynamic SQL. Yet I tried once again with your code it's not working. This query returns only NULL in all the fields when executed with any inputs. what else can I do to get the results I wanted? Kindly answer.

Comment: There was a mistake in the last condition, I did not use the @end_date parameter. I fixed that now. If all parameters are NULL, the query should make an average of all rows (because the second part of each condition is met).

Comment: I fixed it when I tried that query, Yes , it has to calculate average of all rows, but it didn't. I have checked it with and without parameters. It returns only null.

Comment: @aniH Then your data or your stored procedure are faulty. As a general principle, I always assume I made the mistake; you should too. Check this demo and then figure out what you did differently... https://dbfiddle.uk/7AsDEbGr